# proof $\forall f \in C^0[0,1]$ then $\Vert f \Vert _p \le c \Vert f\Vert_r$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let be $r,s \in [1,\infty]$ where $p<r$, then there is a $c>0$ such that $\forall f \in C^0[0,1]$ then $\Vert f \Vert _p \le c \Vert f\Vert_r$

where $\Vert f \Vert _p = (\int_0^1\vert f(x)\vert ^pdx)^ \frac{1}{p}$

and $\Vert f \Vert _\infty = max\{  \vert f(x)\vert : x \in [0,1] \}$ .

This is what I have developed:

1. As $p<r$ then $\vert f(x)\vert ^p \le \vert f(x)\vert ^r$
2. Then $\int_0^1\vert f(x)\vert ^p dx \le \int_0^1\vert f(x)\vert ^r dx$
3. Then $(\int_0^1\vert f(x)\vert ^pdx)^ \frac{1}{p} \le (\int_0^1\vert f(x)\vert ^r dx)^ \frac{1}{p}$

But I guess I'm wrong because point 1. is not necessarily true if $f(x) \lt 1$

Any suggestion as to how to begin?

Comment: "As $p<r$ then $\vert f(x)\vert ^p \le \vert f(x)\vert ^r$" - This is definitely false. Think about it.

Comment: Yes I know is False, How could I start?

Comment: Try the Hölder inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets prove first the next proposition:

If $s,r \in \mathbb R$ are such that $1 \le s \lt r \lt \infty$. Then $\forall f,g \in C[a,b]$ the next happens:

$$i)\  \Vert f \Vert _s \le (b-a)^\frac{r-s}{rs} \Vert f \Vert _r$$

$$ii) \ \Vert f \Vert _s \le (b-a)^\frac{1}{s} \Vert f \Vert _\infty$$

Proof:

For $i)$

Let be $p = \frac{r}{s}$ and $q = \frac{r}{r-s}$,  then $p,q \in (1,\infty)$ and also $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$

Then, by Hölder inequality where $f = f^s$ and $g = 1$ we have:

$$\Vert f^s \Vert_1 \le \Vert 1 \Vert_q \Vert f^s \Vert_p $$

i.e $$ \ \int_a ^b\vert f(x) \vert ^s dx \le \Biggl( \int_a^bdx \Biggr)^\frac{1}{q}\Biggl(\int_a^b\vert f(x)\vert ^{sp} \Biggr)^\frac{1}{p}$$

i.e $$ \ \int_a ^b\vert f(x) \vert ^s dx \le (b-a)^\frac{1}{q}\Biggl(\int_a^b\vert f(x)\vert ^{r} \Biggr)^\frac{s}{r}$$

Then  $$ \Biggl( \int_a ^b\vert f(x) \vert ^s dx \Biggr)^\frac{1}{s} \le (b-a)^\frac{r-s}{rs}\Biggl(\int_a^b\vert f(x)\vert ^{r} \Biggr)^\frac{1}{r}$$

Therefore  $$i)\  \Vert f \Vert _s \le (b-a)^\frac{r-s}{rs} \Vert f \Vert _r$$

For $ii)$

By definition $\Vert f \Vert_\infty = max_{x \in [a,b]}\vert f(x)\vert$

Then $$\vert f(x)\vert \le \Vert f\Vert_\infty \ \ \ \ \forall x \in [a,b]$$

Then $$\vert f(x)\vert^s \le \Vert f\Vert_\infty^s \ \ \ \ \forall x \in [a,b]$$

Then $$\int_a^b\vert f(x)\vert^s dx \le \int_a^b \Vert f\Vert_\infty^s dx = (b-a)\Vert f \Vert_\infty^s$$

Then $$\Biggl( \int_a^b\vert f(x)\vert^s dx \Biggr)^\frac{1}{s} \le (b-a)^\frac{1}{s}\Vert f \Vert_\infty $$

Therefore $$ii) \ \Vert f \Vert _s \le (b-a)^\frac{1}{s} \Vert f \Vert _\infty$$
$$■$$

Then The original problem can be solved applying this general proposition.

Answer (score 1):

As a colleague said, it's [using Holder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality)
$$||f||_r^r = \int_{0}^{1}|f|^rdx=\int_{0}^{1}|f|^r.1dx \leq \left( \int_{0}^{1}(|f|^r)^{p/r}dx 
 \right)^{r/p}\left( \int_{0}^{1} 1 ^{(p-r)/p}dx\right)^{1-r/p}= \left( \int_{0}^{1}|f|^pdx  \right)^{r/p}$$